# How to make icons on XFCE panel work like in Windows?

Tags: launcher, icons, xfce, panel

I don't want Windows Buttons to appear after I click on Launcher icon, I want minimize and maximize windows on click on the same icon that were used to launch the window. Like in Windows or in KDE (Icons-only task manager).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid XFCE doesn't have widget with this functionality. You have either a launcher or a switch widget here. But you can use software like [Plank](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/plank) or something similar, to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I know i'm a bit late, but it might help someone. Install [Dock-Like-Plugin](https://github.com/nsz32/docklike-plugin). After installing it you add it to the panel. So you can create a new blank panel, then after that add the plugin.All applications you open will be shown on the plugin. There is an option to pin the applications. As you can see from the picture below, that is my panel with the docklike plugin, when I minimize, the application goes to its position. You can see running/open applications and the active application.
[image]